# 12.04 Constant freezing after screen lock?

Tags: 12.04, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have a laptop with Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 on it.  About 1/4 of the times I open the lid of the laptop, the screen will turn on, I'll be able to move my mouse around, but clicking/typing is unresponsive.  The only way to get out of this is to do a hard restart (hold power button down).  Then, sometimes Ubuntu won't load after that, and will tell me that it's restarting (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163987/reboots-on-startup)).

Comment: Are you using any "lock on lid close" script?

Comment: I use kubuntu, so the exact menus will be different, but: 1) Go into System Settings->Power Management->Global Settings and see if Lock Screen on Resume is checked (probably isn't).  If it is, turn it off and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: 2) Next, look at Profile Assignments (on same screen) and determine under which scenario(s) (plugged in/not plugged in, battery high/low) the problem occurs and note what power profile that scenario uses.  Switch to the Power Profiles tab (on left) and select the appropriate profile.  That will display all it's user settable parameters.  Remember the settings because you'll probably want to revert to them later.  Set things to do as little as possible, but with short delays to make testing go faster and see if it has any effect.  Make sure you don't go too far and crash a database writing, etc